# Can I do a substring using regex?

Tags: regex

I am newbie to `regex` here's  my question:

**Below is the content of the file:**

```
cts-pdr/comment-primary/:not spamming
cts-pdr/comment-primary/:please remove since not spamming
cts-pdr/comment-primary/:not spamming
cts-pdr/comment-primary/:not spamming
cts-pdr/comment-primary/:Not spamming
cts-pdr/comment-primary/:not spamming
cts-pdr/comment-primary/:please unblock since not spaming
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to match the second part of the colon.
I'd like to capture the whole string i.e.:

```
(please\s.*)? [N|n]ot .*
```

I am not able to get the right match.
Can anyone help?

Comment: No need for regexes here. Split on the colon and take the second part.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to have a non-useless title that actually attempts to describe what you're asking?

Comment: Regex is overkill.This is a simple task using split, as @SergioTulentsev says.

Comment: @Totem see above for the regex that I've used. I am using regex in unix script.

Comment: @underscore_d I am trying to match whole string of the second part of the colon.
KenWhite like sergio suggested could you please elaborate on how to use the split?

Comment: @Farid OK, so please [edit] your title to reflect what you're wanting to do, not just the name of the tool you're currently trying to do it with. Imagine if I created a question called "Computer", for example...

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks for your help. I got my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is update your regex to:

[`(please|[N|n]ot).*`](https://regex101.com/r/rWKE0L/1)

And mabye use a non capturing group `(?:` like:

[`(?:please|[N|n]ot).*`](https://regex101.com/r/rWKE0L/2)

That would match `please` or `Not` or `not` followed by any character zero or more times `.*`

Comment: This worked (?:please|[N|n]ot).*
Thanks for the help :)